# Better way to graph percentage of One Categorical Variable by another in R

Tags: r, statistics, graphs

Looking through the Brfss 2013 dataset (a study that recorded many elements of an observers health habits and outcomes), I wanted to see if there was a correlation between smoking often and being an excessive drinker, by seeing the percentage of the three types of Smokers 'Every Day' 'Sometimes' 'None smokers' that drink often.

This is the code I ended up using:
('drnk3ge5' and 'smokday2' are the respective variables for drinking and smoking)

```
brfss <- brfss2013 %>%
filter(!is.na(drnk3ge5),!is.na(smokday2))

brfss_1 <- mutate(brfss, bngdrnkr = ifelse(drnk3ge5 >= 4,'Yes','No'))
test1 <- brfss_1 %>%
  filter(bngdrnkr == "Yes") %>%
  group_by(smokday2,bngdrnkr) %>%
  summarise(yes_count = n())
test2 <- brfss_1 %>%
  group_by(smokday2) %>%
  summarise(total = n())
test1$total <- test2$total
test1 %>%
  group_by(smokday2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=smokday2,y=(yes_count/total))) +geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Is there anyway to code this clearer and more easily understandable?